# Is it possible to let Postgres automatically retry transactions?

Tags: django, postgresql, transaction-isolation

I'm developing a Django application in which I want to have strong guarantees about the correctness of the data. For this reason, I have `SERIALIZABLE` as the transaction isolation level.

However, during load testing I see some related error messages:

> could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
> DETAIL:  Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during write.
> HINT:  The transaction might succeed if retried.

and

> could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
> DETAIL:  Reason code: Canceled on conflict out to pivot 23933812, during read.
> HINT:  The transaction might succeed if retried.

and

> current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

I do automatically retry the transaction via Django, but I'm uncertain if this solution is actually good. I wondered: **Is it possible to let Postgres automatically retry transactions that failed for those reasons?** Is there maybe something directly in Django allowing me to configure that? (It would not have to be for all transactions; I know the candidates that are failing more often / that are more important)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, PostgreSQL doesn't offer such a functionality. If Django does, that is great, and you should use it.

The SQLSTATEs you should catch are 40P01 (deadlock) and 40001 (serialization failure).

Comment: "If Django does" - I don't know. I have custom code that does it, but I would prefer it being done directly by Django. For example, I wonder if waiting before the next retry / backoff make sense and which parameters would be best.

Comment: @Martinthoma  Waiting generally doesn't make sense. The competing process already finished or already got the lock before you can process the error.  You can retry immediately.  There is no guarantee a new conflict hasn't come along, but there never is.